# ClassCastException with HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android, ssl

I try to establisch a HttpsURLConnection with:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection()
```

but I get an Exception:

```
E/JavaBinder(  901): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
```

But I can't find out, why. The same example is everywhere across the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ClassCastException is telling you that the object being returned is not a HttpsUrlConnection.  The cast you are doing is inherently unsafe, instead you should something like:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
  // do stuff
}
else {
  // error?
}
```

As to the reason its not giving you an Https version, what url are you providing it with?  My guess is you are giving it http:.. instead of https:...

Comment: That's right, also what @erickson says. I want to get a connection to a http:// url but want to send a client certificate (as in X.509) to this server for authentication, so I thought that I need a https connection. Do you maybe know how to provide a certificate with an http connection?

Comment: I'm not sure, you probably want to start a new question for that.

Comment: I think, what I want is not possible :-S

Comment: I too get this exception, but I am using https, any idea what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

What is the URL? It looks like you are using a plain "http:" scheme URL, but expecting an HTTPS connection.

Comment: Hi erickson , i am facing the same problem with https url, can you suggest something.

Comment: @KartikShah Post a new question and provide detail of your situation. Without that, I can only assume that you are mistaken, and that you are accessing a resource with HTTP.

Comment: @erickson the scenario is same, i think the issue is with the server, because it has multiple nodes and and some configuration is going wrong on some node. 
I am saying this because the same code works sometimes and doesnt the other time, i will post a new question once i am sure its not a server issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @KartikShah Perhaps the server is erroneously redirecting to HTTP some times. Is there a load balancer or cluster involved?